# How to see code coverage of tests in Xcode 10 for C++ project

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode10

I have a C++ Xcode project on Mac, and I'd like to see how much code coverage my tests have. If I were building on linux, I would pass a few extra flags to GCC and then use `gcov`.

What I'm looking for is a way to do something similar on Mac, either through Xcode or through the command line.

[This link](https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/code-coverage-and-xcode-6b2fb8756a51) describes how to get the code coverage tools that Xcode has built in to work, but unfortunately those seem to only work for ObjC or Swift. All the other articles I've found have been similarly unhelpful (either very out of date or only for Swift/ObjC).

I'm not sure how to get this running through the command line, since I'm not even sure what command(s) Xcode uses to build my project (I assume `xcodebuild`, but I'm not sure what arguments).

I'm fine with doing this either through the command line or through Xcode, whichever is easier.

Any help would be appreciated, please let me know if you need any more details.

Details:
I am using `Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61)`.

Comment: I've tagged this `xcode10` because I've found lots of tutorials for doing this in older versions of Xcode, but none have worked for me. Feel free to remove this if it's the wrong tag.